# How can I privately bookmark a message in Discord?

Tags: privacy, bookmarks, discord

I can privately bookmark a message in Slack with the "Save for later" feature as follows:

[image]

How can I privately bookmark a message in Discord?

---

From my understanding:

- pins are not private and not available on all servers,
- similarly, bookmark emojis  are only possible on some servers, and I don't know if that's private.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

In the menu for the message (available on all platforms; I think it's 3 dots that show up on hover on the website), there's an option to "Copy message link". Simply use this option and save the link as a browser bookmark or in another external app. You could even send it as a Discord message to yourself, in a private server or something (which will [show the server name automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvx7v.png)); this is the most built-in way available.

Answer (score 1):

Use your web browser bookmarks / favorites.

Here is the link to the Spanish-Mexico help article about using bookmarks in Safari for Mac: https://support.apple.com/es-mx/guide/safari/sfri22092/16.0/mac/11.0

At the page footer, there is a link to change the country. Some countries, like the United States, offer more than one language. I'm not including the United States - English because the Apple Support website automatically redirects me.

You might have to click the **More** button, the three dots button, on the message you want to bookmark, then **Copy the message URL** or something like that. Below is an image showing the **More** menu for Discord in **Spanish - Latinamerica**:

[image: Message More menu]